# AWS IAM Assume Role and Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, assume-role

I have SSO Roles for Compute team in my organization in which AWS managed policies and  inline policies included as per their requirements.
Now, as per current requirement of Compute team, they need access to RDS and DocumentDB. Therefore, i added required inline policies
in SSO Roles.Now, before implementing SSO roles, i need to validate either these added inline works well or not. thus for testing, i created
test user [name: Testuser] in testing account with account id 123456789012 [example] and but no permission granted to this IAM User and then created
IAM role => custom trust policy => added user arn in trust relationship as follows.

Trust Policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Testuser"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I added all  new inline policies as per compute team requirement in this IAM assume role. Logging as IAM user and switch role to the same account [123456789012].
I validated my added inline policies for RDS and DocumentDB and it was good, Testuser has access of RDS and DocumentDB in test environment.
My question is that, Am i doing correct steps to validation ? or, some other steps required to validate results. i checked AWS documentation where assume role
only  for cross account but here i login as IAM user in same account and switch role in same account[123456789012]. this is my confusion. please help.

I need to validate my steps.

Comment: Please format and remove irrelevant details.  I can't make much sense of your question